# How to adjust floaty button on google maps in swift 5?

Tags: ios, position, padding, swift5, floating-action-button

```
Floaty.global.rtlMode = true
floaty.addItem("Start Navigation", icon: UIImage(named: "navigation-2 icon")!, handler: { item in
let dialogMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm Map Type", message: "Please select map Type for navigation", preferredStyle: .alert)
            // Create OK button with action handler
            let apple = UIAlertAction(title: "Apple Map", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                print("Apple Map")
                self.openMapWithApple()
            })
            // Create Cancel button with action handlder
            let google = UIAlertAction(title: "Google Map", style: .cancel) { (action) -> Void in
                print("Google Map")
                self.openMapWithgoogle()
            }
            //Add OK and Cancel button to an Alert object
            dialogMessage.addAction(apple)
            dialogMessage.addAction(google)
            // Present alert message to user
            self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            //self.present(dialogMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
            floaty.close()
        })
        self.view.addSubview(floaty)
```

**Floaty button in iOS**
I'm new to iOS I have created a floaty button now I want to give padding to that button but nothing is working for me please help
GitHub link of floaty button https://github.com/kciter/Floaty

[Refrence link](https://github.com/kciter/Floaty)

[Floaty button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nibq.jpg)

how do I set this button ?

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to explain what "Floaty button" is, and you need to show what you've tried to do.

Comment: I'm Sorry is it ok now ? @DonMag

Comment: OK - that's a little better. But you need to show what you've done with it already... show what you ***want*** to do with it (*"give padding"*????)... and show what you've **tried** to accomplish that. We can't guess at what you want.

Comment: I have shared code of button you can see and I want to set this button a little up like googlemaps my location getter button as shown in screenshot on bottom right corner of the screen. Thanks I really appreciate your effort @DonMag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick look at the "Floaty Button" code...

Distance from right-side of view, or, since you are setting `Floaty.global.rtlMode = true`, distance from left-side of view:

```
floaty.paddingX
```

Distance from bottom of view:

```
floaty.paddingY
```

So, you could, for example, do this:

```
  floaty.paddingX = 40.0
  floaty.paddingY = 40.0
```

[image]